# Can I use Tensorflow's C++ API without Bazel?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am currently playing around with different APIs of Tensorflow. I succesfully use the C API within a C++ project, and it is fine so far. However I thought about using the C++ API to just check it's functionalities. However I do not have access to Bazel during the usage of the C++ API, which might be a problem. On the Tensorflow C++ API homepage (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) it is stated that:
"The C++ API is only designed to work with TensorFlow bazel build. If you need a stand-alone option, use the C API."
The thing is: it is no problem for me to use bazel to build the C++ API. However, the actual compilation of code must be done without Bazel for my project. Unfortunately it is not clear to me whether the C++ API only requires Bazel for building, or also during execution...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `the actual compilation of code must be done without Bazel for my project`? I am using the Tensorflow C++ API within a CMake / Make structured project. I had to adapt the Tensorflow configuration using a combination of CMake functions `add_custom_target`, `add_custom_command` and `add_dependencies` to control the Bazel build. Bazel will only build Tensorflow into a complex structure explained [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html). This is where you will find the compiled libraries and its dependencies.

Comment: As baptiste suggests, you can collect the products of building TensorFlow with Bazel and use them in your own building process. However, there is no support for this, as in, there is no documentation for which files and paths exactly you need to use, and what compilation flags you need to get everything working. It is possible but currently the supported paths are: either build all your application with Bazel or use the C API. The path I took was to use Bazel to build a DLL with a simplified API for my purposes, and it was tricky enough. Bazel would only be required for building in any case.